# ERROR: lwcollection_construct: mixed dimension geometries: 0/2

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am running g a intersection between two data sets. Both have same Projection system 27700 but still I am getting this error: `ERROR:  lwcollection_construct: mixed dimension geometries: 0/2`

Below query I am running:

```
Create table TableA as Select Clm1, Clm2, st_intersection(TableB.shape, TableC.shape)from TableB, TableC where st_intersects(TableB.shape, TableC.shape) = 'True';
```

Also whenever I view these tables in PGAdmin TableB's geometry can be seen but not for TableC (it says `3D geometry not rendered`).

I read about this case on this website and they all are saying to set the SRID but this is not the thing because my both data sets have same SRID.

Even TableB is made by intersection of the data sets who have 27700 projection in them.

Please can any one help over it?

Comment: Obviously  ST_Intersection returns both points (0 dimension) and areas (2 dimentions). That is normal and I am not sure what is the problem that lwgeom library has with the data.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I got the solution by running ST_Force2D on TableC and by that it made all data in 2D which looks perfectly fine.